# Django Rest Framework Delete forbidden

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently struggeling with some django rest framework issues. I want to define a delete request for my APIView.

This is my view.py:

```
class Employee(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        employee = EmployeeModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        employee = EmployeeModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        employee.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/v1/employeelist/', views.EmployeeList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/employee/<pk>', views.Employee.as_view())
]
```

Serializer:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

The get method works fine when I call /api/v1/employee/4 for instance. The UI of the API shows me the allowed methods: GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS but when I send a delete request I always get the error 403 forbidden.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: can you show off the **EmployeeSerializer** class

Answer (score 1):

Set `authentication_classes = []` for your APIView. DRF has SessionAuthentication and BasicAuthentication by default, and you need to disable it

Comment: It works, but strange thing is, that Postman could use DELETE method, but my asynchrous Javascript got 403 Forbidden, before I added authentication_classes = []

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the serializer class is unless you use get_serializer() and even then it's working fine with your get request. I believe your issue for the delete is that you may be using SessionAuthentication or BasicAuthentication (the defaults for DRF). Try making your view csrf_exempt.